# Comparing values to detect statistically significant difference

Tags: mean, standard-deviation

I want to compare 2 values to see if there considerable significant different between them.

Basically these values comes from 2 credits score bureau providers (score 1 and score 2). The score 3 is just the avg between score 1 and 2. and we base our decision on this score 3.

```
+---------+-----------+----------+----------+
+       id+    score 1+   score 2+   score 3+
+---------+-----------+----------+----------+
+  006abXi+        100+        50+        75+
+---------+-----------+----------+----------+
+  006fsRe+        600+       550+       575+
+---------+-----------+----------+----------+
+  006csXm+        320+       350+       335+
+---------+-----------+----------+----------+
```

We are trying to identify if it is worth to keep using score 2, and just based our decision on the first credit bureau.

My current sample is a bit under 3500 records. And to have a very rough idea, I did an average of the score 1 and score 2 and see if there is much difference between them

```
+---------+-----------+----------+----------+
+      avg+    score 1+   score 2+   score 3+
+---------+-----------+----------+----------+
+         +     556.92+    584.14+    570.53+
+---------+-----------+----------+----------+
```

Doesn't look much but I do not think this will be the right way to base this decision on. I am wonder if there is any formula or sort of graph that I can use to visualize and be able to base my decision in some more scientific background?

Answer (score 1):

You want to "see if there is **considerable** **significant** different between them".

With a sample size of 3500, your difference will very likely be *significant*. You could check using some appropriate [paired difference test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paired_difference_test) like the paired t-test or Wilcoxon signed rank test.

Whether the difference is *considerable* depends on what you want to do with it, what constraints exist in your task, and what you are willing to tolerate.

As far as visualization is concerned, I would suggest a histogram for the score differences.

Comment: Thank you yeah i was working on histogram and did a few charts of how many people are between certain ranges, that helped a lot, I will check out the rank test

Comment: With large datasets, the significance tests usually always state significance, so it is more important to look at the effect. Visualization is a good tool in this regard.